# SSIS project deployment error : "deploy_project_internal"

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis

I added SSIS as a feature to an **existing** SQL Server 2016 instance using the SQL Server installer, downloaded SSDT (2015), built a simple import package, and can't seem to deploy.  The error is below.

Things I have tried:

1. Checking the registry key path
2. Modifying permissions per this [article](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/fixing-sql-2012-ssis-deployment-error-6522-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client)
3. The suggestions in the other 4 other threads in this forum that come
   up when I search "deploy_project_internal"
4. Repairing newly-installed SSIS (verified that it's installed and running)
5. Restarting the server and the SQL Server after each attempt
6. Verifying the TargetServerProperty was correctly set to SQL Server 2016
7. Running ISDeploymentWizard.exe and deploying from the Catalog (same error)

I've spent most of my day working this issue.  Is it just a bug?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the error message from SSDT, ISDeploymentWizard.exe and right-clicking from the Catalog.

```html
    TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
------------------------------

The required components for the 64-bit edition of Integration Services cannot be found.  Run SQL Server Setup to install the required components.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The required components for the 64-bit edition of Integration Services cannot be found.  Run SQL Server Setup to install the required components.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteToPipe(SmiContext pipeContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe.ExecuteAndSend(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.RaiseError(SysMessageId messageId, SysMessageSeverity severity, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.GetDtsPath(Int16 use32bitOn64, String& path)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.GetISServerExecPath(Int16 use32bitOn64, String& path)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64 deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString projectName)
. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27222)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.4451&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=27222&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]